# Background disappears in PDF when distilling the Illustrator EPS

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-acrobat

Requesting suggestion to find solution for the below issue:

Input (Illustrator EPS): Strokes are visible with Illustrator EPS.

[image]

Output (EPS -> PDF generated through Distiller): After using Distiller, strokes found missing where the blue color layer occurs.

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like translucent fill became opaque in the conversion... So the lines are still behind it, but you just can't see them. Well without knowing your entire process in detail, my guess would be the cause of it is the pdf version you used. [Any PDF below version 1.4 doesn't support transparency](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/transparency-flattening-acrobat-pro.html): "To retain transparency without flattening when you create PDF files, save your file as Adobe PDF 1.4 (Acrobat 5.0) or later."

Comment: The lines are still behind it and this issue occurs during EPS to PDF creation using Adobe 9.0.

Comment: Could you check the settings to make sure there's nothing there that could get rid of transparency? That's my best guess with this amount of information. You might have to describe all the steps you took to convert it.

Comment: If working in Illustrator to create EPS, why use Distiller to create PDF versus save as PDF to get better control of PDF settings and manage transparency natively in Illustrator?